# Why is the body cut off on the right on all mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile

I'm working out the mobile bugs on a site I've been working on for a while and this is the first one I'm struggling with. I'm checking it out on an ipad and the body doesn't extend all the way to the right of the browser. It seems to be cut off by 30ish pixels. I can't find where this would be coming from in the stylesheet. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I might knock it out?

You can see it here: 192.237.164.63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your viewport settings?

**EDIT**

Nevermind, I've discovered your issue. It lies in .container.black ul.

If I change the user-agent to iPad in desktop safari, this element exceeds *out* of the viewport, however on mobile safari, it simply renders the rest of the text on a new line. Although, the viewport is still somehow extended. Remove the width style, it should be fixed. I tested this in Safari develop and Chome development tools.

Comment: Daniel was right the first time around. I was using the standard Zen theme viewport settings, which didn't cut it. I added some params that should have been in there and it started to work. Still a weird display bug in ipad vertical mode, but landscape and both modes for iphone look good now.

Comment: Glad I could help. What's up with vertical mode?